# HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL() only returning partial information?

Tags: javascript, python

I want to get an image from the canvas in a webpage and am attempting to use .toDataURL() to do so.  My objective is to get the image, write the info to a DB, and then do whatever to it later.

I am using this javascript code:

```
    function makeImageValue() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('meme');
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
      return dataURL
    }

    function setInputValue(input_id, val) {
        document.getElementById(input_id).setAttribute('value', val);
    }

setInputValue('image_string', makeImageValue())
```

which utilizes the .toDataURL() functionality as documented here: [in Mozilla documentation](http://%09function%20makeImageValue()%20%7B%20%09%09var%20canvas%20=%20document.getElementById('meme');%20%09%09var%20dataURL%20=%20canvas.toDataURL();%20%09%20%20return%20dataURL%20%09%7D%20%20%09function%20setInputValue(input_id,%20val)%20%7B%20%09%20%20%20%20document.getElementById(input_id).setAttribute('value',%20val);%20%09%7D%20%20setInputValue('image_string',%20makeImageValue())).  My understanding is that this basically returns a really long string that looks something like:
`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACWCAYAAABkW7XSAAAEYkl...`  The length of what I get back is 1594 characters long.

I then tried to use the following python script to decode it:

```
import base64

# Separate the metadata from the image data
head, data = mystring.split(',', 1)

# Get the file extension (gif, jpeg, png)
file_ext = head.split(';')[0].split('/')[1]

# Decode the image data
plain_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)

# Write the image to a file
with open('image.' + file_ext, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(plain_data)
```

However, it came out as blank.  I then went to a [website that does this for you](https://www.site24x7.com/tools/image-to-datauri.html), and it gave me back a similar string, but it was 551374 characters long.  When I run the above python script, it works.  This tells me that I am doing something wrong with my .toDataURL().

Am I interpreting what the .toDataURL() does incorrectly?  Shouldn't I be getting everything I need to reconstruct the original image?

Other Information:
I am sending the information using this form from my html:

```
<form  method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div>
      <input id="image_string" name="image_string" type="hidden" value="placeholder">
      <input class="btn btn-success" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload Meme">
    </div>
</form>
```

I don't think the html is the problem, but wanted to include for thoroughness.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was calling the .toDataURL function before the canvas was populated.  I moved the call of this function into a button click action and this solved the issue.

Turns out the 1594 character length string simply corresponded to the blank canvas that I had drawn on page load.